# Will the Gigabyte GeForce GTX1050TI G1 Gaming 4G work with my motherboard?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card, pci-express, pci

I want to upgrade my Acer Aspire XC-605. I want to get a better PSU, a bigger case and a better graphics card. I believe my motherboard is called MS-7869 DB.SRPCN.001 (I'm not sure). It has a PCI-Express 16x slot but the graphics card that I want to buy has a PCIe 3.0 x16 connection.

My question is: Will the MS-7869 DB.SRPCN.001 motherboard (with PCI-Express 16x slot) **work with** the Gigabyte GeForce GTX1050TI G1 Gaming 4G (with PCIe 3.0 x16 connection)

Thanks!

Comment: It will certainly work, it's just you may or may not get the maximum performance out of the card.

Comment: "Will the MS-7869 DB.SRPCN.001 motherboard (with PCI-Express 16x slot) " - PCI-E is backwards compatible.

Comment: @vembutech GDDR5 is dedicated graphics memory on the GFX card itself, DDR3 is the slot-type on the motherboard for system memory (RAM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It will most definitely work. You have a PCIe 16x slot on your board, which any GFX card will fit into. Since PCIe is backwards compatible, most cards will work on most boards.

However, one thing to be wary of is TDP and your power supply. If you buy a 1000W power supply (which is more than enough and very pricey), you're going to be able to pull 1000W before that power supply gives up the ghost and shuts the system down. If you only get a 450W PSU, you'll only be able to pull 450W before the computer shuts down. If your CPU, GPU, RAM, etc. max out your power supply, it won't work, but that's an unrelated issue to compatibility.

I digress, YES, this card is compatible with this motherboard.

Comment: The 1050Ti draws power directly from the PCIe slot.  It doesn't require a large power supply and doesn't need any additional power connections to the motherboard.

Comment: I understand, I was just saying that in the future if Ath upgrades their PC again, they may require a better PSU (which they intended to get in the first place.)

Comment: Makes sense.  OP can also go to https://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator which will tell them, based on their components what PSU size they actually need.